# Transfering 1d array into 2d array without numpy

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to put the contents of a user input 1d array into a fixed 4x7 2d array. My current method tries to slice the user input into 4 parts to insert them into the fixed array, but this will push the entire part of the sliced array into the list instead of just replacing the values inside the list.

How do I make it so that I would be able to replace the value of the **fixedarr** array with the user input directly?

```
userinput = []
fixedarr = [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]

new = []
new = userinput[a:b:1]
if a == 0:
    a = 4
    b = 8
ttuple = new
fixedarr.insert(0, ttuple)
```

**Edit:**
The input is a string and uses this function to convert its characters into integers. It will be then put inside the **userinput** array and stored inside the **fixedarr**. I do this because I would like to multiply the **userinput** array with a different one in the future.

```
def reenter(a):
    b = input("Name: ")
    return b

name = input("Name: ")

while len(name)> 28:
    print('Input must be below or equal to 28 characters')
    name = reenter(name)
    if len(name) < 28:
        break

for x in name:
    num = ord(x) - 96
    if num == -64:
        num = 0
    userinput.append(num)
```

So for example the numbers converted from the input are [1 2 3 4 5 6], it will be put inside the fixedarr array and the output should look like this:

```
fixedarr = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
```

But currently, my code would output like this

```
fixedarr = [[1,2,3,4], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the value of the fixedarr array with the user input directly"?

Comment: I mean instead of pushing the userinput[] array into the fixedarr[] list, it would change its values directly. I put in an example of output. I'm sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to convert a 1d array into a 2d array. You can do it either using a while loop, for loop or list comprehension.

using a while loop:

```
fixedarr = []
name = str(input("Name : "))

i=0
name_len = len(name) # name lenght
while i < name_len:
    fixedarr.append([name[i:i+4]])
    i += 4
```

using for loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(name), 4):
    fixedarr.append(name[i:i+4])
```

using list comprehension:

```
fixedarr = [name[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(name), 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can undestand yoy, you want to replace your fixedarr list n with user input,so just insert on n position, like:

```
fixedarr[n] = userinput
```